# R - stargazer 4 star cutoffs

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

I would like to use 4 `star.cutoffs` -- `c(0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001)` -- using `stargazer`.

```
library(stargazer) 

m1 = lm(disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars) 
stargazer(m1, type = 'text', star.cutoffs = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001), digits = 2)
```

It seems that it is only possible to get 3 star cutoffs.

Any idea to get 4 cut offs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to specifying `star.cutoffs` you should also specificy `star.char` .

This works fine for me:

```
stargazer(model1, model2,
          type = "text",
          star.char = c("+", "*", "**", "***"),
          star.cutoffs = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001),
          notes = c("+ p<0.1; * p<0.05; ** p<0.01; *** p<0.001"), 
          notes.append = F)
```